# Netsuite workflow condition pulling on date field was edited

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to set a condition in a NetSuite workflow so it only triggers when the date of emp. Termination = today and the date that same field was edited also = today. This is what I have but it is not working:
`(DECODE({systemnotes.field.id}, 'custentity_emp_termination_date',{systemnotes.date})={today}) and {custentity_emp_termination_date} = {today}`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

{systemnotes.field.id} is not a real field.  It implies a multi-level join (from current record to System note to Field), which NetSuite does not allow outside of SuiteAnalytics.  The "Name of Field" can be viewed if you put "{systemnotes.field}" in a saved search to see how it is formatted since it'll have to be exact.

Replace the code with:

DECODE({systemnotes.field}, 'NAME OF THE FIELD',{systemnotes.date})